# Removing full object from a value

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

**Helper Class**

```
public class HomeScreenChatsHelper implements Comparable  {

private String ID;
private String Name;
private String Image;
private String From;
private String Seen;
private String LastMessage;
private String LastMessageTime;

public HomeScreenChatsHelper(){
}


public HomeScreenChatsHelper(String id, String name, String image, String from, String seen, String lastmessage, String lastMessageTime) {
    this.ID=id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Image = image;
    this.From = from;
    this.Seen = seen;
    this.LastMessage = lastmessage;
    this.LastMessageTime = lastMessageTime;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String id) {
    ID = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return LastMessage;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    LastMessage = message;
}

public String getTime() {
    return LastMessageTime;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    LastMessageTime = time;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return From;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    From = from;
}

public String getSeen() {
    return Seen;
}

public void setSeen(String seen) {
    Seen = seen;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public int compareTo(Object comparestu) {
    long compareage= Long.parseLong(((HomeScreenChatsHelper)comparestu).getTime());

    long a = Long.parseLong(LastMessageTime);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    }
    return Long.compare(a,compareage);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof HomeScreenChatsHelper)) return false;

    HomeScreenChatsHelper that = (HomeScreenChatsHelper) o;

    return getID().equals(that.getID());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getID().hashCode();
}
```

**Activity**

```
          for(HomeScreenChatsHelper str : mChats) {
                if (str.getID().equals(ID)) {
                    mChats.remove(ID);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

There are a ton of tutorials on how to do it and I've spent the past week looking for a solution and I still don't have it. Is there anyway I can remove an whole object by just specifying just the ID? I wont have the values of all the other fields so I just want to remove a particular object by its ID. Also I cant use the clear option because I need the other data. So can someone help me out please?

With the present code nothing happens. No errors but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using java-8 you can filter the list, result will be the `List<HomeScreenChatsHelper>` that does have `HomeScreenChatsHelper` with same `id`

```
List<HomeScreenChatsHelper> mChats = new ArrayList<>();

//filter
List<HomeScreenChatsHelper> result = mChats.stream()
                                     .filter(str->!str.getId().equals(Id)).
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or by using `Iterator`

```
// Iterator.remove() 
    Iterator itr = mChats.iterator(); 
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    { 
        HomeScreenChatsHelper x = itr.next(); 
        if (x.getId().equals(Id))  }
            itr.remove(); 
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. is `mChats` a List containing `HomeScreenChatsHelper` objects?
I assume so. If this is the case, then you can change your `foreach` loop into the normal loop

```
//Assuming mChats is List e.g ArrayList
for (int i = 0; mChats.size(); i++){
            if (mChats.get(i).getID().equals(ID)) {
                mChats.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

     On the 2nd Line

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in Java 8 or later is with [`Collection#removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
mChats.removeIf(str -> str.getID().equals(ID));
```

By the way, the convention in Java is for fields to begin with a lowercase letter.